# SyntaxHighlighter with $().load Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntaxhighlighter

**Edit:** Editing for clarity and actual use. Actual use might even make this situation easier?

I'm building a style guide and I want to include source code to the common styles/patterns for people who will be using the guide. My plan is to abstract out all the heavy HTML code modules into external files and pull them in using jQuery then use [SyntaxHighlighter](http://phara0h.com/jqueryMob/hoofdstuk1.html) to highlight what's being presented on the screen. The HTML below shows my intent and what I'd like to do.

I've removed all JavaScript for now since it doesn't add any value to the question at hand. I'll update with anything I come up with.

```
<div class="sg-section">
    <div class="sg-section-body">
        <div data-load="markup/pagination.html"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sg-section-code">
        <small>Source Code</small>
        <pre class="brush: js">
            <!-- This is where I want to print out the contents  -->
            <!-- of the 'sg-section body' above and show it's source -->
        </pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can get the data loaded with a simple `$('[data-load]'.each();` statement, but I'm having a hard time printing the result out into `sg-section-code` and getting it hightlighted.

**Conclusion:** Switched to [Prism](http://prismjs.com/). Works beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:**

```
  function loadScript(placeholder){
    var $p = $(placeholder);
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $p.load($p.attr('data-load'),function(response){
        $p.parent().append(response).end().remove();   
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred;
}
```

**to remove the placeholder and insert your code from external html directly, this should solve your problem that only display the placeholder instead of real code.**

your problem is that load is an async method, and you don't know when to call SyntaxHighlight.all();

so, the solution come into my head is use jQuery.Deferred object. let `load` tell you when it fininsh loading all external scripts.

first extract the method loadScript

```
function loadScript(placeholder){
  var $p = $(placeholder);
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  $p.load($p.attr('data-load'),function(){
    deferred.resolve();
  });
  return deferred;
}
```

then push all the task into an array, finally use $.when().then() to notify when all the script has been loaded, then call SyntaxHighlighter.all();

```
$(function(){
  var q = [];
  $('[data-load]').each(function(item){
    q.push(loadScript(item));
  });
  $.when.apply($, q).done(function(){
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  });
});
```

Comment: unfortunately when I try this, I just get `<div data-load="test.html"></div>` returned twice through SyntaxHightlighter. This is what happened when I tried to use `$().load("test.html", function(response){ ... });` since `load`'s second parameter is a callback method if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/xujihui1985/eQ5f8/) sorry try loadScript(this) instead of item

Comment: yes, the second parameter is a callback which will be called when it successfully load from remote, and `deferred.resolve();` to indicate it finish loading

Comment: $.when is a method to wait until all defererd object resolved and it will kickoff the callback in it's done() method, so my idea is to wait until all external html loaded then kickoff SyntaxHighlighter.all()

Comment: @Sean I have, but it's still not working. Tomorrow when I have the time and energy I'll try a separate HTML page without the rest of my fluff (which I excluded in my code sample above) and see if those scripts alone make it work then figure out how to implement it in the rest of my code.

Comment: @AmitJoki yes what's the problem?

Comment: @AmitJoki have you debugged into `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` to see what it did before use the 'complete callback' of $.load?

Comment: it's funny someone give me a downvote, if you thought your solution is better just show your code

Comment: @Sean, I upvoted you :-). We're getting there...the code renders correctly but SyntaxHighlighter won't syntax highlight it! I still haven't tried isolating the code though...maybe later today if I get some time. You're help is very much appreciated.

Comment: We're so close. I had it running once but it didn't work on a refresh. I think the issue is that deferred doesn't have the function assigned to it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47102/discussion-between-sean-and-ehorodyski)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Get Markup Pages
    $("[data-load]").each(function (index) {
        $(this).load($(this).attr("data-load"),function(){SyntaxHighlighter.all()});
    });
});
```

This should work, as `SyntaxHighlighter.all();` is executed after test.html is loaded

Comment: @EHorodyski, I don't think so, its given in jquery docs. Look at here https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @AmitJoki do you realize `SyntaxHighlighter.all()` will be called everytime in the loop? if there are 10 elements, it will be called 10 times while 'SyntaxHighlighter.all()' this method should only be called once, don't you think this is terrible?

Comment: @AmitJoki don't think problem too easy, your solution work, not good